# Destination airport switched, 7 days before arrival. Am I allowed compensation ? (EU)

Tags: air-travel, eu, compensation

I had a flight on TUI from Morocco to Paris Roissy planned.

7 days before the flight, the company changed the airport of destination to Paris Orly, and we had to pay for a taxi home.

In this situation, can I claim a compensation under EU law?

Comment: Why did you have to pay for a taxi? There seem to be many options with public transport.

Comment: Transport is free for parisians from Roissy, and it's fast to where we live. Orly is the other side of town, and we would need to take at least three different transport types to get home (it was over 80 minutes if I remember correctly). Also the Orlybus is often full and you can't get in, and the Orlyval for two people is almost as expensive as a taxi.

Answer (score 1):

Providing the ‘applicability’ rules are met, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation_261/2004 if a passenger’s destination is an airport at a city with multiple airports and rerouting results in the passenger being taken to another of those airports, the airline must pay for transport for the passenger to the original intended airport or an agreed nearby destination.

Comment: It is not quite obvious that the article you are quoting from (8.3.) applies in this case, as there are exceptions when cancellations and flight changes are announced in advance. Usually in any civil matter (European law), it is also in most cases expected that an aggrieved party is required to assist in minimizing any applicable loss. That's why I asked if a taxi was really required, when there is public transport available. Even if the airline were required to pay for transport, it would not necessarily be required to pay for a presumably higher taxi bill.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbo Agreed